# Capturing Alternate Point of Contact Information

Tags: forms, information-architecture, information-design

Does anyone know of some good articles or documentation I can read for identifying the best practices to follow when designing the information architecture (forms) for allowing users to provide alternate contact information?

My objective is not gather information that is not required, such as:
Do not collect phone from contacts who will not be called.

The scenarios I am looking at are:

1. User does not need a secondary point of contact.
2. User needs more than one secondary point of contact.
3. User identifies a primary point of contact that is not themselves.
4. In all scenarios the user can choose if themselves or the point of contact can receive calls or digital notifications.

The designs I have created led to a lot of yes/no questions which then showed additional form sections based on the answer. Users I have tested this with seem to enjoy this form and it captures all information they would need. however, although works well, it feels like I am reinventing the wheel or over complicating what should be a simple process.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding an "Optional secondary contact(s)" section at the bottom of the form. Here users can input as many contacts as they need. This example shows that the user has input one secondary contact, and may continue adding more as needed:

[image: Sample Wireframe]

If your system limits these to 2, then instead of using a table here, you can just have 2 optional sections (i.e. "Optional secondary contact #1" and "Optional secondary contact #2").